# Hiding navigation links from 'SSRS Subscription properties' page

Tags: reporting-services

How can I hide navigation links from SSRS Subscription properties page? Need to hide Home, My Subscription etc... links. I have already removed the links from the report link.

Comment: I am confused. Are you refereing to the links to hyperlinks/reports that go out to clients or authorization within the SSRSManager?

Comment: Hyperlinks (home, My Subscriptions, Help) which are visible on the SubscriptionProperties.aspx page

Comment: When we create a subscription of SSRS report, a new page opens with Subscription properties. I want to remove navigation links from that page.

Comment: I bet you could create a user with authentication credentials and almost zero authorization rights, then only grant specific access to your reports. No "My Reports" access.